# Authorization Error Using AWS S3 Buckets

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, node.js, cloud-storage, amazon-s3

```
node s3_listbuckets.js
Error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"]
    at ClientRequest.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:3)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:219:14)
    at Object.request (https.js:305:10)
    at features.constructor.handleRequest 
...
XXX
... 
{
  message: 'Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"]',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  region: 'XXX',
  hostname: 's3.XXX.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true,
  time: XXX
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who ventures down this path.  If you get this error then it is 99.9% caused by a typo in the AWS credentials provided.   Could be an extra `\n` or maybe just an empty space   at the end of a string or a missing character.  But if you are smart like me then you're typo could be elusive like this:

I googled for "regions aws codes" so I could get the proper code for us east region.  Google provided a table with a list of codes, so I copied and pasted it into my credentials and I kept getting this `Invalid character...` issue.

It wasn't until I got credentials file from a coworker when it the error went away. So then I compared line by line and noticed absolutely no difference in characters......But I was wrong.  I took the region code from my configuration and put them into a [Unicode converter](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/) and discovered this:

`us‑east‑1` translates to `us\u{2011}east\u{2011}1`

Where as

`us-east-1` translates to `us-east-1`

You can guess which version I had copied from Google?...I've learned my lesson and I hope anyone venturing here doesn't make the mistake I had.